# Can I run Ubuntu Touch on my device?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a question for Ubuntu Touch un-support phone device.
I have got Device Phone, but i have checked for Ubuntu Running Movie via Youtube.
so, i want to know for unsupport android device setup.

and My phone device hardware satisfy the system(Entry level Ubuntu smartphone) requirements.

It is check through http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/operators-and-oems

so,,
First, Can i installation ubuntu touch ?
Second, if you do not installation, Installed on all Android devices, do you have any support plan?

Thanks Ubuntu,

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure about the last part of your question, the First Second and support plan part.

So since we don't know what is the model of your phone, and assuming it is possible to 'flash' ubuntu touch on it base on there is someone on youtube successfully do it, you can try message that person on how to do it, or read all the information [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install), or try search on [this side](http://forum.xda-developers.com/sitesearch.php?q=ubuntu).

But bare in mind, there is no any warrenty if your phone bricks or broken after 'flashing', so **flash it on your own risk** mate :)